# Nested if logic gives unexpected results

Tags: matlab, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

I need to calculate the bus fare according to the following rules:

- The fare for any distance within the first 1km is 2USD.
- Then, the fare is 0.25USD per whole km till 10km.
- Then, the fare is 0.10USD per whole km for any distance above 10km.
- There is a discount of 20% for people younger than 18 or 60 and older.

My code doesn't work correctly for distances less than 1km. Can someone advise please?

This is the code I'm using:

```
function f=fare(dist1,age)  

   dist=round(dist1);    
     if age>=18 && age<=60    
       if dist<=10    
         f=(2+round(dist-1)*0.25)    
       else    
         f=(2+round(dist-1)*0.1)    
       end    
     else    
       if dist<=10    
         f=0.8*(2+round(dist-1)*0.25)    
       else    
         f=0.8*(2+round(dist-1)*0.1)    
       end    
     end
```

Comment: @AnderBiguri, done

Comment: Um, could you be more precise? I've used enter key and it shows to use four spaces. I'm pretty new here in stackoverflow.

Comment: It's okay, I formated it for you - try to get use to the formatting here on SO, there is a preview of your post, make sure you get the formatting right before posting or you could upset many people

Comment: oh okay. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: The answer for 0.2km and age=65 must be 1.6 and I get 1.4. There must be an error somewhere but when I use if age<=1 and then specify the value, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what rounding you want. Do you want people only to pay for each completed km?

Comment: your problem is actually `round(dist-1)` can produce a negative value if dist is less than 0.5, you could potentially fix this bug by changing it to `max(round(dist-1),0);` to prevent it going to the negative

Comment: @julian59189, each completed km yes.

Comment: @GameOfThrows, I think so. Let me try.

Comment: I did this way and it works now


function f=fare(dist1,age)
dist=round(dist1)
    if age>18 && age<60
    if dist>1 && dist<=10
        f=(2+round(dist-1)*0.25)
    elseif dist>10
        f=(2+round(dist-1)*0.1)
    else
        f=2
    end
else
    if dist> 1&& dist<=10
        f=0.8*(2+round(dist-1)*0.25)
    elseif dist>10
        f=0.8*(2+round(dist-1)*0.1)
    else
        f=1.6
    end
end


Excuse the code this way. Can't get the code window in comments.

Comment: @VenkatKaushik dont put code in comments. Please, consider taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You want to use kilometers as integers, as a threshold to add a bit more to the fare.

However, you are rounding the distances with `round`.

This means that a distance of `0.2` becomes `0`, but a distance of `0.6` becomes `1`. in the first case, `round(0-1)->-1` so you have a negative fare.

Overall, your program's logic is messy and hard to follow, thus very specific errors like this arise. For example, in your code, you charge `0.1` for every kilometer, if someone goes higher than 10km. Its cheaper to travel 11km than 10km. Try it.

This is an alternative tidier way of coding the same thing:

```
function f=fare(dist,age)  

% first we are going to calculate the distances.
% there are 2 important distances: from 1 to 10 (9km)
% and from 10 to inf. We call these dist1 and dist 2 respectively

dist1=0;
dist2=0;
if dist>10
  dist1=10-1;
  dist2=floor(dist-10); % only charge if they have gone the whole km. 1.5km gets rounded to 1km.
elseif dist>1
  dist1=floor(dist-1);
end

% Compute the whole fare
f=2+dist1*0.25+dist2*0.1;

% apply discount
if  age<18 || age>60
   f=f*0.8;
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd demonstrate how this problem can be vectorized, in case you need to run the function many times on different inputs. The solution below accepts `dist` and `age` arrays of any size, as long as it's equal for both arrays.

```
function out = q41742418(dist,age)
%% Check inputs for compatible size
if any(size(dist) ~= size(age))
  out = 0;
  return;
end
%% Constants and definitions:
L_1 = 1;          % Length of the 1st price section.
L_2 = 9;          % Length of the 2nd price section.
P_0 = 2;          % Price of the 1st section (    0    < x <=   L_1  )
P_1 = 0.25;       % Price of the 2st section (   L_2   < x <= L_1+L_2)
P_2 = 0.1;        % Price of the 3rd section ( L_1+L_2 < x < +Inf    )
D_AGE_LOW  = 18;  % Minimal age for no discount.
D_AGE_HIGH = 60;  % Maximal age for no discount.
DISCNT_PCT = 0.2; % Discount percentage
% Define a rectangular function for convenience:
rect = @(x,L,R)+(x > L & x <= R);
%% All the rest:
out = (P_0 ...                                                % The 1st L_1 km
     + P_1*( dist > L_1)     .* min(floor(dist-L_1),L_2) ...  % The next L_2 km
     + P_2*( dist > L_1+L_2) .* floor(dist-(L_1+L_2)) ) ...   % Rest of the distance
    .* (1 - DISCNT_PCT*(~rect(age,D_AGE_LOW,D_AGE_HIGH))) ... % Apply a discount?
    .* (age > 0) ...     % Handling the edge case of unborns
    .* rect(dist,0,Inf); % Handling the edge case of 0 distance.
```

See comments inside the code. This was tested against [**Ander**'s implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41742855/3372061) using:

```
for dists = 0.1:0.3:15
  for ages = 0.1:10:70
    assert(fare(dists,ages) == q41742418(dists,ages),...
      ['Discrepancy for (distance,age) = (' num2str(dists) ',' num2str(ages) ')']);
  end
end
```

I took the liberty to provide my own logic for when the age is exactly `0`, `18` and `60`, or when the distance is `0`.

Answer (score -3):

If we keep your current implementation, You are missing an "if" loop for the case where distance is less than 1 km. Secondly, if the distance covered is greater than 10 Kms, the distance between 1 km and 10 km is going to cost $0.25 instead of $0.1.
Following should work properly:

```
function f = fare(dist1,age)
    dist=round(dist1);
    if age>=18 && age<=60
        if dist <= 1
            f = 2;
        elseif dist<=10
            f = (2 + round(dist-1)*0.25);
        elseif dist > 10
            f = (2 + 9*0.25 + round(dist-10)*0.1);
        end
    else
        if dist <= 1
            f = 1.6;
        elseif dist <= 10
            f = 0.8*(2 + round(dist-1)*0.25);
        elseif dist > 10
            f = 0.8*(2 + 9*0.25 + round(dist-10)*0.1);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: No, this solves the problem he has, but does not do what OP descrived, because more things are wrong in his code

Comment: You're right.! I just tried to solve the basic problem. I personally prefer the explanation you gave in your answer.
I thought it would be simple for OP to understand If I keep his own implementation.

Comment: @user5203299, the code doesn't work for dist=9.6
Mine doesn't for 10.7

Comment: Well, I get $3.4 with discount and $4.25 without discount for a distance of 9.6 km.